# Keep/search/retrieve my quotes

Tags: windows, information-management

I have hundreds of saved quotes in numerous text files.

Is there a dedicated software to enter quotes (preferably with a tagging feature), then search them by topic, author, etc.? Or is my best bet to build my own database via MySQL or the like?

I am on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Have you looked at Evernote?    https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2014/12/10/use-tags-organize-evernote/

Comment: Would a web app work for you?

Comment: @Alex I can at least try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Quote Collection](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-quotes-collection) template on Simitless. Althoug the template gives you a basic idea of what your collection can look like, you can always:

- add/remove/change the names of the columns. The way it works is that you get predefined spreadsheet-columns-like fields that you can select from to track/collect only the data you need.
- import and export your data at any time.
- search your quotes by any parameter. Once your app is created, simply go to your app directly (use the URL that is assigned to your app when you build it), click the "+" next to "Filter by", select what to search to then see instant results.

Here is a little screenshot what it looks like with some "dummy data" I input into the template:

[image]

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand.

Comment: Thanks. Does this procedure involve payment?

Comment: You can input quite a bit of data for free (we are running under a freemium model) and if you need more storage, users, etc. you can upgrade at any time. Here is the [pricing](https://pricing.simitless.com/#usd). In any case, if your database becomes huge and you don't want to spend money on it, you can always export your data, i.e. you are never locked in.

Answer (score 2):

As your quotes are in text files, I would first suggest looking at a software like CintaNotes: http://cintanotes.com

Alternatively, you can also build your own database. For personal local needs, I would suggest one that does not require a client-server architecture. You could use a sqlite database. If you need to create graphical templates for your searchs, you could use Kexi, which store projects into sqlite databases: http://www.kexi-project.org/